# Linker error while linking DataFlowSanitizer to LLVM IR

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am using pre-built LLVM/Clang 3.8.0 binaries on Ubuntu 16.04.2, 64 bit. I tried to lift a minimal program to LLVM IR, then link the IR to DataFlowSanitizer libraries to produce executable code. In the second step, the process throws a bunch of linker errors.

```
#include <sanitizer/dfsan_interface.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
  int i = 1;

  dfsan_label i_label = dfsan_create_label("i", 0);
  dfsan_set_label(i_label, &i, sizeof(i));

  return 0;
}
```

> clang -c -emit-llvm -fsanitize=dataflow test2.c -o test2.bc
>
> clang -fsanitize=dataflow test2.bc -o test2
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o:
>   In function `_start':(.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   /tmp/test2-c642ef.o: In function `dfs$main':
>
>   test2.bc:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to`dfs$dfsan_create_label'
>   test2.bc:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `dfs$dfsan_set_label'
>
>   /tmp/test2-c642ef.o: In function`dfs$dfsw$dfsan_create_label':
>   test2.bc:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to
>   `dfs$dfsan_create_label'
>
>   /tmp/test2-c642ef.o: In function`dfs$dfsw$dfsan_set_label':
>   test2.bc:(.text+0x1e4): undefined reference to `dfs$dfsan_set_label'
>   clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Any idea what might I be doing wrong?